# Declare variable MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

My question might be simple for you, if you're used to MySQL. I'm used to PostgreSQL SGBD and I'm trying to translate a PL/PgSQL script to MySQL.

Here is what I have :

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER pgl_new_user 
AFTER INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE m_user_team_id integer;
    SELECT id INTO m_user_team_id FROM user_teams WHERE name = "pgl_reporters";

    DECLARE m_projects_id integer;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT project_id FROM user_team_project_relationships WHERE user_team_id = m_user_team_id;

    OPEN cur;
        ins_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO m_projects_id;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE ins_loop;
            END IF;
            INSERT INTO users_projects (user_id, project_id, created_at, updated_at, project_access) 
            VALUES (NEW.id, m_projects_id, now(), now(), 20);
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END//
```

But MySQL Workbench gives me an error on `DECLARE m_projects_id`. I don't really understand because I've the same instruction two lines above...

Any hints ?

EDIT: neubert solved this error. Thanks.

But yet, when I try to insert into users :

```
Error Code: 1329. No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed
```

Do you have any idea ? Or better, do you know how I can get a better error message ?

Comment: Take a look here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25405/event-scheduler-no-data-zero-rows-fetched-selected-or-processed

Answer (score 43, accepted):

All DECLAREs need to be at the top. ie.

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER pgl_new_user 
AFTER INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE m_user_team_id integer;
    DECLARE m_projects_id integer;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT project_id FROM user_team_project_relationships WHERE user_team_id = m_user_team_id;

    SET @m_user_team_id := (SELECT id FROM user_teams WHERE name = "pgl_reporters");

    OPEN cur;
        ins_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO m_projects_id;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE ins_loop;
            END IF;
            INSERT INTO users_projects (user_id, project_id, created_at, updated_at, project_access) 
            VALUES (NEW.id, m_projects_id, now(), now(), 20);
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END//
```

Comment: Right ! That's actually solve my problem (in pgsql, you can't `DECLARE` before `BEGIN`, almost the same). I had another error with this script : `Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger`. I replaced the first `SELECT` and I solved it. But then, it still doesn't work. If you want to help me, I've edited my post.

Comment: Try replacing the `SELECT @m_user_team_id` with `SET @m_user_team_id :=`. I've updated my post.

Comment: just a note: "BEGIN DECLARE m_user_team_id integer;" -> to remember to use DECLARE on top of codes

Comment: Thank you! My problem was that i needed the DELIMITER logic. Just goes to show you that code examples can show a lot more than the original intention!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with neubert about the DECLARE statements, this will fix syntax error. But I would suggest you to avoid using openning cursors, they may be slow.

For your task: use INSERT...SELECT statement which will help you to copy data from one table to another using only one query.

[INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html).