# Oracle to MySql syntax changes

Tags: mysql, oracle

I'm working on converting a whole project from Oracle to mySql. I've been trying to figure out where the syntax is wrong here. Any ideas?

CREATE TRIGGER payment_check BEFORE DELETE ON members FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE v_payment_due DECIMAL(6, 2); // this line returns error

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 0):

MySQL syntax is quite a bit different from Oracle. Your trigger should look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER payment_check
  BEFORE DELETE ON members
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_payment_due DECIMAL(6, 2);

  SET @v_payment_due := 1.23;
END;
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=138290f75f3f9c01f45e4e44048bc06d) and [the answers to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841455/declare-variable-mysql-trigger)

Answer (score -1):

in mysql syntax is like

```
 DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
    BEFORE DELETE
    ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- statements
END$$    

DELIMITER ;
```

for your reference refer this [link](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-before-delete-trigger/)